# Sql Query for finding Orders having same order lines

Tags: sql, oracle

How I can write a query that can find me orders having same order lines (details)?

Sample Data

**Table: Order**

```
ORDER_ID
--------
A
B
C
D
```

**Table: OrderDetails**

```
OrderID ProductID
------------------
A   ProductX
A   ProductY
A   ProductZ
B   ProductX
B   ProductY
C   ProductZ
D   ProductX
D   ProductY
D   ProductZ
```

Now I want to pass `ProductX,ProductY,ProductZ` and get back `A` and `D`.

Can this be done in one query?

Comment: Assuming that there is no Order table..even then the required result can be got rite...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this is what you want?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Orders.OrderID
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON Orders.OrderID = OrderDetails.OrderID
WHERE OrderDetails.ProductID IN ('ProductX', 'ProductY', 'ProductZ')
GROUP BY Orders.OrderID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Also note that `Order` is a reserved keyword and should not be used as a table name.

Comment: Assuming that there is no Order table..even then the required result can be got rite...

Comment: @jpw, came across an issue with the query, this also returns records that have more than 3 products. Like 'ProductX','ProductY','ProductZ','ProductA'.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT OrderId  FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT o.OrderId, p.Product 
FROM Orders o
INNER JOIN OrderDetails p 
ON o.OrderId = p .OrderId 
WHERE p.Product IN ('ProductX', 'ProductY', 'ProductZ') ) tab
GROUP BY OrderId 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT P.OrderID
FROM Order1 P JOIN OrderDetails D ON
           P.OrderID = D.OrderID
WHERE P.OrderID IN (SELECT OrderID FROM OrderDetails WHERE ProductID IN ('ProductX', 'ProductY', 'ProductZ'))
Having Count(P.OrderID)=3
GROUP BY P.OrderID
```

## [FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1d159/15)

Answer (score 0):

I have done the required thing without using the Order table..

```
SELECT id from ProductT
group by id
having count(*)=3;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5ec8/2)